# How to get pip install to install packages into the 64bit version ,not 32bit one?

Tags: python, python-3.x, path, pycharm

I have both python 32bit and 64bit installed but when I use pip install I'm installing into the 32bit directory. Instead, I want to install to the 64bit directory because I want to access those packages in PyCharm when 64bit python.exe is set as the project interpreter. How can I do this?

Comment: are you using venv/anaconda?

Comment: No,I'm using system interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly run `path/to/64bit/python.exe -m pip install <package>`.